# How to continue loop if it fails in hardhat

Tags: hardhat, error

I am using hardhat.

I have a async function main() that i want to loop with a delay of 5 seconds. The problem is that, it exits the loop when an error happens, and it happens the first time...

```js
(async () => {
  while (true) {
    await main() // < -- THIS IS MY FUNCTION
    await sleep(5000) < -- THIS IS MY DELAY FUNCTION I MADE
  }
})().catch(e => { /*WHEN I COME HERE, IT MEANS ERROR, I WANT TO CONTINUE*/ })
```

in python it looks like this

```py
while 1: 
    try:
        main()
    except:
        time.sleep(5)
        continue()
```

is there a way to make infinite loop function in hardhat OR is there a way to wait for a good response and ignore the error in hardhat OR how can i make my error loop again my main() function ?

I have been searching for hours on stackOverflow, stackExchange... found nothing.

Thank you in advance for any answer and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular try/catch.

```js
(async () => {
  while(true) {
    try {
      await main();
      // await sleep(500); // this is an option too
    catch(e) {
      await sleep(500);
    }
  }
})();
```

A complete example:

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

let counter = 0;

async function main() {
  console.log("counter: ", counter);
  // Will fail on every odd number
  counter++;
  if (counter % 2 === 1) {
    throw Error("Error");
  }
  return counter;
}

(async () => {
  while (true) {
    try {
      const result = await main();
      console.log("result: ", result);
      await sleep(5005); // Will sleep for 5 seconds
    } catch (e) {
        // Nothing to do here?
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.